# Why AWS Cognito access token life is 1 hour hard set, is it not too long? why aws not allow to set it by console or sdk?

Tags: security, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm willing to set access token expiry to say 10 seconds, but its not available on Console or via SDK. I wonder if anyone able to set is manually. 
so why this is set to 1 hr hard coded. why not flexible to set as per user preference.

PS : I am using free tier of AWS and using Java SDK.